# Why does 'abc'.hasOwnProperty('length') == true

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Please help me understand prototype inheritance in this case:

Why does `'abc'.hasOwnProperty('length')` return true but `'length' in 'abc'` throws an error?

Comment: Why would this be downvoted? It might have a duplicate somewhere, I suppose, but being a duplicate doesn't make a question *bad*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression `'abc'.hasOwnProperty('length')` is interpreted by JavaScript as

```
(new String('abc')).hasOwnProperty('length')
```

Every (capital-S) String instance has its own `length` property, which gives the length of the string.

JavaScript (lower-case s) string instances are primitives and do not have any properties at all. The use of a string primitive as the left-hand side of the `.` operator causes the string primitive to be implicitly wrapped in a String object (at least conceptually; the runtime doesn't *really* have to instantiate a transient object) and that's where the `.length` property comes from.

The expression `length in 'abc'` throws an exception because there's no implicit promotion of the *primitive* `'abc'` to a String instance with the `in` operator. Thus since a primitive cannot have *any* properties, and the concept makes no sense, it's an exception.

Comment: Great explanation, it makes sense now. Thank you!